# Incompatible types using generics and rxjava

Tags: java, generics, lambda, rx-java

Stumbled upon incompatible types error cause of which I don't understand.

> error: incompatible types: Flowable cannot be converted to Flowable
>       where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Packet declared in method getPackets(Class)

Why is this piece of code wrong?

```py
public Flowable<Packet> getPackets() {
        .....
}

public <T extends Packet> Flowable<T> getPackets(Class<T> type) {

    return getPackets().filter(type::isInstance);
}
```

`Flowable` and `filter()` are part of `rxjava`, `filter()` looks like this:

```py
public final Flowable<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)
```

Comment: At what line is the error happening? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return getPackets().filter(type::isInstance);
```

returns a filtered view of `getPackets()`, which is of type `Flowable<Packet>`.

However, `T` can be *any* subclass of `Packet`, not just `Packet`. And because Java generics are invariant (e.g. `List<Dog>` isn't a `List<Animal>`), this isn't compatible.

You'd need to cast the `Flowable`:

```
return getPackets().filter(type::isInstance).map(type::cast);
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed it by using ofType() instead of filter().